# how to check the element with the class?

Tags: jquery

I am using a jquery code for my keyboard control. When I press on the keyboard, the yellow block will jump on to the next block. I am trying to find out how to check the element of 'row2' with the class called 'span0hr' then do something.

```
if (event.keyCode == 37) 
  {   //left
    if(parseInt(current_row) <= 1)
    {
      return false;
    }

    for(var i=2; i< parseInt(current_row);i++ )
    {
      var yellowbgnextdivwidth1 = $(".div_"+current_col+'_'+i).css( "width"); 
      var yellowbgnextdivwidthsplit1 = yellowbgnextdivwidth1.split("px");
      totalwidth_current1=parseInt(totalwidth_current1)+parseInt(yellowbgnextdivwidthsplit1[0]);
    }   
    var currentrowleft = $(".rowSubPgm div.pgmFirstRow:first").css( "margin-left").split("px");
    currentrowleft1 = currentrowleft[0].split("-");
    currentrowleft2 = currentrowleft1[0].split("-");

    if(typeof(currentrowleft2[1])!= "undefined")
        currentrowleft1 = currentrowleft2[1];
    if(typeof(currentrowleft1[1])!= "undefined")
      currentrowleft = currentrowleft1[1];
    else
      currentrowleft = currentrowleft[0];           
      var currentdivwidth = yellowbg.css( "width").split("px");
      //alert("-"+(parseInt(currentrowleft)-parseInt(currentdivwidth))+"px");


      if(current_row == 2 && currentdivwidth[0] == 517)
      {
        current_row--;
      }
      else if(current_row == 2 && currentdivwidth[0] == 250)
      {
        $('.span1hrfor30mins').each(function(i,e)
        {
          if($(e).hasClass('row2') && $(e).hasClass('span1hrfor30mins'))
          {
            $('.rowSubPgm').css( "margin-left", "-"+(rowwidth)+"px" );
            $(e).attr('row2'); $(e).removeClass('span1hrfor30mins').addClass('span1hr');
          }
        });

        if($(e).hasClass('span0hr'))
        {
            alert("let do something");
        }
      }


      if(current_row > 2 && currentdivwidth[0] > 250)
      {
        current_row--;
      }
  }
```

The trouble are lies somewhere in this code:

```
if($(e).hasClass('span0hr'))
{
  alert("let do something");
}
```

When I press on the keyboard left arrow button, it supposed to check the element of 'rows2' with a class called 'span0hr' then do something but what happens with the code is  it is not doing anything. It don't check with the element at all, I guess that I have made the incorrect if statement to check for the element.

Does anyone know how I can check the element called the 'rows2' with the class called 'span0hr'?

Comment: Do you have some more code to look at? Possible some HTML?

Comment: Please provide HTML and [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: What do you pass to `e`? Why `$(e).attr('row2');`? `row2` is not an attribute. `id`, `name`, `value`, ect. are attributes.

Comment: `rowwidth` should not be in parentheses and should be defined.

Comment: @PHPglue can you tell me how to check the element of row2 if i have the class called span0hr? i tried this if($('span0hr').hasClass('row2')) but i cant get pass it. any idea?

Comment: @PHPglue Thank you very much for your help which it much appriecated. I can see the problem is solved. Are there any chance if i can give you a good rep? cheers!

Comment: Try `if($('.span0hr').hasClass('row2')){$('.span0hr').each(function(){$(this).removeClass('span1hrfor30min').addClass('span1hr')}`. Just remember that jQuery selectors are just like CSS, unless it's implicit, like `.hasClass()`, `.removeClass`, and `.addClass()`; then they are just a String without the selector.

Comment: "check"? What do you mean? check a checkbox? "Look at"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are attaching your handler to the onkeydown or onkeyup events. The onkeypress events are not raised for control keys on all browsers.

Comment: @PHPglue, I am trying to check the element of row2 if it has a class called 'spanhr' then do something. do you have any idea how i can get pass it? if you need to see my web app: http://testbox.elementfx.com/test.php. I am sure you know what i am trying to achieve.